# On_message wait for the user to react to the message or timeout before bot sends another message with the reaction again

Tags: python, discord.py

If you DM the bot it will send a message and add some reactions, it then waits for the user to add reaction before doing something.

My problem is if the user DMs the bot again, it will send another message and if the user reacts to any of the bot messages, bot will do the things twice or more depending on how many messages you got from the bot.

Is there a way to make the bot to not send another message if there's a current message with reaction and wait for the user to react first before the bot can send another message with reaction again? Thanks.

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        dm = await message.channel.send('test')
        await dm.add_reaction("1️⃣")
   
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣"]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=15, check=check)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                # do something here
 
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await dm.delete()
            break
```

Comment: what's the purpose of that while loop?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, and why did you add a while loop?

Here's the fixed code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        # Sending the message and adding reactions
        msg = await message.channel.send('Test')
        await msg.add_reaction('1️⃣')

        check = lambda reaction, user: user == message.author and str(reaction) in your_list_of_reactions

        try:
            # Waiting for the reaction
            reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=15.0)

            if str(reaction) == "1️⃣":
                # do something

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.delete()

    # Adding this so the rest commands will work
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

- [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: Thanks for replying lucas! I tried it, but still the same. Whenever you dm the bot it keeps giving the message + adding reaction and when you react to it, it does the #do something multiple times depending on how many messages + add reaction was sent by the bot. I put the while loop, so they can click reaction 2,3,4,5 it gives information while the 1 makes a channel. Also tried using time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.last_timeStamp).total_seconds(), it works blocking the message but problem with it is other people can't message the bot.

Comment: If you want to make such dynamic reaction system you should take a look at `discord.ext.menus`, it's still in beta and doesn't have docs yet, but there are a few examples in [discord.py discord server](https://discord.gg/dpy) do `?tag menus` or `?tag embed menu` in #testing to see some examples. To install it `python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus`

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it! Checked the github and I think, using that couldn't be done in DMs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making a database for every message. Thanks for the people who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late, but here is a solution that worked for me

In your "check" statement you should add this to it

```
and reaction.message == msg
```

So it will look something like this

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣"] and reaction.message == msg
```